# collecting data into table

Tags: php, html, collections

i have a file 'colecting-data.html' with this code :

```
<html>
 <body>

   <form action="collect.php" method="get">
     name : <input type="text" name="name">
     email : <input type="text" name="email">
     telephone: <input type="text" name="telephone">
     <input type="submit" value="save">
   </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

i when to creat "collect.php" file to collect all the data (name email telephone) 
and save then in another file "save.html" inside a **table** .

it will help me a lot if any one know how to do that .

Comment: did you try something in php ?

Comment: i understand html , but php its so hard

Comment: @Peter better to start learning PHP from basic.

Comment: yes i will , but i need to find solution to this today , help me if you know the solution

Comment: "_i need to find solution to this today_" Last day, well. Take a look at [$_GET](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to get the values from your form, maybe [foreach](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop over them and maybe [file_put_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to save to a file (watch your file permissions). Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Very quick & dirty answer, remember to sanitize your inputs.

```
<?php
//collect.php
$html = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><table>";
foreach($_REQUEST as $k=>$v) {
  $html .= "<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v</td></tr>";
}
$html .= "</table></body></html>";
file_put_contents('save.html',$html);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can use this to learn, start with the basic way to do this before going for more advanced options...

First off, your form needs to be a POST, not a GET.

```
<form action="collect.php" method="POST">
```

This will POST the values to collect.php.

On collect.php, you'll need to collect the values;

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']) { 
    // Do Something 
    ;}

    if(isset($_POST['email']) { 
    // Do Something 
    ;}

    if(isset($_POST['telephone']) { 
    // Do Something 
    ;}
?>
```

From here, you can set the posted values as variables and then do whatever you want with them.

Comment: i need to save the data into a table . this is my problem